# Удаление объектов при перезагрузке игры в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть MainCamera на которой висят скрипты. Соответственно, мне нужно чтобы объект не удалялся при загрузке нового уровня (сцены).
Оставляю объект строкой: `DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject)`.
Нужно при входе в главное меню удалить прежнюю MainCamera.
Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: То есть вам нужен объект-синглтон? Ну это который всегда один и копию нельзя сделать?

Comment: Да, мне нужен объект-синглтон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот скрипт объекта-синглтона.

```
public sealed class UnitySingleton : MonoBehaviour {
    public static UnitySingleton Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake () {
        if (Instance) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
        else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            Instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Принцип работы такой. Awake вызывается сразу как только объект создан (например, при загрузке сцены с ним). `static` означает, что это поле не экземпляра, а класса, то есть одно на всю программу. Если там `null`, значит объект еще не создан, и мы вызываем `DontDestroyOnLoad` для нашего объекта и инициализируем поле. После этого там уже не `null`, а наш экземпляр. Тогда при попытке создать новый объект или добавить скрипт этот новый объект уничтожится.

Я не уверен насчет того, будут ли вызваны `Awake` других скриптов на этом объекте, если мы уже создавали сингтон. Если будут вызываться, можно убрать их в префаб и добавлять его как дочерний синглтона в блоке `else`.

Comment: `Я не уверен насчет того, будут ли вызваны Awake` - будут, если эти скрипты по Script Execution Order расположены ДО UnitySingleton.

Comment: Возможно,где то я ошибся ,но объект удаляется при загрузке на новую сцену.Код полностью скопировал , но так как первый раз работаю с объектом-синглтоном , то мог напартачить.

Comment: У вас есть какие-нибудь предположения касательно этого ?

Comment: Смог найти решение.Нельзя один скрипт поставить на пару объектов(public static UnitySingleton Instance { get; private set; }).